# Two WordPress Sites (separate DB) on One Windows Server?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a server that already runs a WordPress site and I wanted to know if there is a way to add another entirely different WordPress site operating on its own Database on the same server. How can this be done on a Windows server?

Comment: perfectly valid question (I had same question). Don't know why someone down-voted it (I up-voted it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this. The first is to just create a separate MySQL database for the new site. You can do this from either PHPMyAdmin or from the MySQL console fairly easily.

```
CREATE DATABASE `my_new_wordpress_db`;
```

Then when you do the second wordpress installation use the new database instead of the first database when it asks you for a database name.

Alternatively you can put both installations in the same database but use different table prefixes instead. During the install wordpress provides a "table prefix" option which you can change to something else to allow both sites to be stored in the same database at the same time. You can also find this option on on line 62 of the `wp-config.php` file.

```
$table_prefix  = 'wp_';
```

Comment: Thanks BW, appreciate your help.